# Create single wix installer for two visual studio projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, installation, heat

I'm using `heat.exe` to harvest Debug (or Release) directory of my visual studio project using this script in post-build event:

`call "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\heat.exe" dir "$(TargetDir)." -var var.WixDemo.TargetDir -dr INSTALLFOLDER -cg Binaries -ag -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -o "$(SolutionDir)WixSetup\$(ProjectName).Binaries.wxs"`

I would get a single installer with two features:

1. project A
2. project B

The problem is that this two projects refer the same dll (`xyz.dll`), so, both harvest processes create a component for this file with same Id.

---

**Edit**

This is my output file after harvesting release dir.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dir325E6775ACBC3561D5CA2F51CFCCC7E8" Name="WixDemoFeature1">
                <Component Id="cmp22AE0957A805CEDAC8D05EF04AE18D5E" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil9EDCA091AB8E6440E9D83A815255C794" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature1.TargetDir)\xyz.dll" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpFCBDB8083076AA83E1B67540ADFECC9D" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="filAA36C3D42B58D430C889BE47087CA911" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature1.TargetDir)\WixDemoFeature1.exe" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp8BCDCA87324BD346D955DDB4318E80BD" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil69700DBD0795710A0AE5DC17574128D5" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature1.TargetDir)\WixDemoFeature1.exe.config" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="WixDemoFeature1Binaries">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp22AE0957A805CEDAC8D05EF04AE18D5E" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpE0CAA29B7BB706D56252E85F7C1DDD0A" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp8BCDCA87324BD346D955DDB4318E80BD" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dir325E6775ACBC3561D5CA2F51CFCCC7E8" Name="WixDemoFeature2">
                <Component Id="cmp22AE0957A805CEDAC8D05EF04AE18D5E" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil9EDCA091AB8E6440E9D83A815255C794" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature2.TargetDir)\xyz.dll" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpE0CAA29B7BB706D56252E85F7C1DDD0A" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil3A3B754D2B216E86025902C3A826545D" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature2.TargetDir)\WixDemoFeature2.exe" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpFB159630D6E1604557E20776A46EB6B3" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil060CF132A168E46D3C4C1C24CA1AEFF4" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature2.TargetDir)\WixDemoFeature2.exe.config" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="WixDemoFeature2Binaries">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp22AE0957A805CEDAC8D05EF04AE18D5E" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpFCBDB8083076AA83E1B67540ADFECC9D" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpFB159630D6E1604557E20776A46EB6B3" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

These two xml have same ID for component "xyz.dll" and so i can't use both "WixDemoFeature1Binaries" and "WixDemoFeature2Binaries" in my Product.wxs.

**I would like to get these instead:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dir325E6775ACBC3561D5CA2F51CFCCC7E8" Name="WixDemoFeature1">
                <Component Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature1.xyz.dll" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil_WixDemoFeature1.xyz.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature1.TargetDir)\xyz.dll" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature1.WixDemoFeature1.exe" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil_WixDemoFeature1.WixDemoFeature1.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature1.TargetDir)\WixDemoFeature1.exe" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature1.WixDemoFeature1.exe.config" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil_WixDemoFeature1.WixDemoFeature1.exe.config" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature1.TargetDir)\WixDemoFeature1.exe.config" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="WixDemoFeature1Binaries">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature1.xyz.dll" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature1.WixDemoFeature1.exe" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature1.WixDemoFeature1.exe.config" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dir325E6775ACBC3561D5CA2F51CFCCC7E8" Name="WixDemoFeature2">
                <Component Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature2.xyz.dll" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil_WixDemoFeature2.xyz.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature2.TargetDir)\xyz.dll" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature2.WixDemoFeature2.exe" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil_WixDemoFeature2.WixDemoFeature2.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature2.TargetDir)\WixDemoFeature2.exe" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature2.WixDemoFeature2.exe.config" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil_WixDemoFeature2.WixDemoFeature2.exe.config" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WixDemoFeature2.TargetDir)\WixDemoFeature2.exe.config" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="WixDemoFeature2Binaries">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature2.xyz.dll" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature2.WixDemoFeature2.exe" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp_WixDemoFeature2.WixDemoFeature2.exe.config" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target dir is designed for debugging on the developer machine, not for gathering files to package.

Be that as it may, you have a few options, including:

- Heat accepts an XSL transform to apply before it emits the .wxs file. With XSL, you can filter out the Component and ComponentRef elements you don't want.
- Use a [project reference](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html) for Project A and Project B in WiXSetup and [harvest](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestprojects.html)  their outputs. You'd then have to harvest xyz.dll separately or hand-write a Component for it. Manually create two Features and reference the xyz Component in both. (I'm assuming the WiXSetup is a Visual Studio project created from the WiX Setup Project template.)
- Use MSBuild's [Copy task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) to create your package layout and harvest that. The Copy task can create hardlinks instead of actually copying. (Almost all types of Visual Studio projects are MSBuild projects.)

---

A simplistic XSLT for the updated question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  exclude-result-prefixes="wix">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Preserving the order of attributes only for aesthetic reasons -->

  <xsl:template match="//wix:Component">
    <xsl:variable name="source" select="wix:File/@Source" />
    <xsl:variable
      name="baseId"
      select="concat(substring-before(substring-after($source, '$(var.'),'.TargetDir)'), 
              concat('.', substring-after($source,'\')))" />
    <Component>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('cmp_', $baseId)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Guid">*</xsl:attribute>
      <File>
        <xsl:attribute name="Id">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('fil_', $baseId)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="KeyPath">yes</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Source">
          <xsl:value-of select="wix:File/@Source"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </File>
    </Component>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//wix:ComponentRef">
    <!-- ComponentRef nodes are interleaved with text() nodes. Want positions 2, 4, 6, ... -->
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="(position() - 1) div 2" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="source" select="//wix:Component[$index]/wix:File/@Source" />
    <xsl:variable
      name="baseId"
      select="concat(substring-before(substring-after($source, '$(var.'),'.TargetDir)'), 
              concat('.', substring-after($source,'\')))" />
    <ComponentRef>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('cmp_', $baseId)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </ComponentRef>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, how can i obtain my target using XSLT? thank you again.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask for code, but I couldn't resist the [kata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_(programming)). It'll be better next time.